# Keep a VBScript window on top, as well as adding a logoff button

Tags: vbscript, timer

I have a piece of script, courtosey of the user Hackoo, but two things are wrong with it. First, the window needs to stay on top, it shouldn't be able to be exited from the taskbar, it needs to be on the bottom right corner of the screen (above the taskbar) and it needs to have a button on it below the text that says "Log off". Of course, the log off button needs to log off the computer. Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,ws,nMinutes,nSeconds,sMessage
Title = "Session Timer"
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
nMinutes = 20
nSeconds = 0
sMessage = "<font color=Red size=2><b>You have"
'Open a chromeless window with message
with HTABox("lightBlue",100,250,0,630)
.document.title = "Session Timer"
.msg.innerHTML = sMessage
do until .done.value or (nMinutes + nSeconds < 1)
    .msg.innerHTML = sMessage & "<br>" & nMinutes & ":" &   Right("0"&nSeconds, 2) _
    & " minutes of session time remaining</b></font><br>"
    wsh.sleep 1000 ' milliseconds
    nSeconds = nSeconds - 1
    if nSeconds < 0 then 
        if nMinutes > 0 then
            nMinutes = nMinutes - 1
            nSeconds = 59
        end if
    end if
loop
.done.value = true
.close
end with
ws.Popup "Your session time has finished. You will now be logged         off.","5",Title,0+48
'*****************************************************************
Function HTABox(sBgColor, h, w, l, t)
Dim IE, HTA, sCmd, nRnd
randomize : nRnd = Int(1000000 * rnd)
sCmd = "mshta.exe ""javascript:{new " _
& "ActiveXObject(""InternetExplorer.Application"")" _
& ".PutProperty('" & nRnd & "',window);" _
& "window.resizeTo(" & w & "," & h & ");" _
& "window.moveTo(" & l & "," & t & ")}"""
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run sCmd, 1, False
    do until .AppActivate("javascript:{new ") : WSH.sleep 10 : loop
    end with  'WSHShell
    For Each IE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").windows
        If IsObject(IE.GetProperty(nRnd)) Then
            set HTABox = IE.GetProperty(nRnd)
            IE.Quit
            HTABox.document.title = "HTABox"
            HTABox.document.write _
            "<HTA:Application contextMenu=no border=thin " _
            & "minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no sysmenu=no             SHOWINTASKBAR=no >" _
            & "<body scroll=no style='background-color:" _
            & sBgColor & ";font:normal 10pt Arial;" _
            & "border-Style:inset;border-Width:3px'" _
            & "onbeforeunload='vbscript:if not done.value then " _
            & "window.event.cancelBubble=true:" _
            & "window.event.returnValue=false:" _
            & "done.value=true:end if'>" _
            & "<input type=hidden id=done value=false>" _
            & "<center><span id=msg>&nbsp;</span><br>" _
            & "<input type=button id=btn1 value=' OK ' "_
            & "onclick=done.value=true><center></body>"
            HTABox.btn1.focus
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "HTA window not found."
    wsh.quit
End Function
```

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that i don't think that we can stay always on the top, but anyway just give a try for this modification, now you want it at the right corner not on the left and i added the button to Logoff the session:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,ws,nMinutes,nSeconds,sMessage,Command,Executer
Title = "Session Timer"
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
nMinutes = 20
nSeconds = 0
sMessage = "<font color=Red size=2><b>You have"
'Open a chromeless window with message
with HTABox("lightBlue",130,300,1070,600)
.document.title = "Session Timer"
.msg.innerHTML = sMessage
do until .done.value or (nMinutes + nSeconds < 1)
    .msg.innerHTML = sMessage & "<br>" & nMinutes & ":" &   Right("0"&nSeconds, 2) _
    & " minutes of session time remaining</b></font><br>"
    wsh.sleep 1000 ' milliseconds
    nSeconds = nSeconds - 1
    if nSeconds < 0 then 
        if nMinutes > 0 then
            nMinutes = nMinutes - 1
            nSeconds = 59
        end if
    end if
loop
.done.value = true
.close
end with
ws.Popup "Your session time has finished. You will now be logged off.","5",Title,0+48
Command ="cmd /c Shutdown.exe -l -f"
Executer = WS.Run(Command,0,False) 
'*****************************************************************
Function HTABox(sBgColor,h, w, l, t)
Dim IE, HTA, sCmd, nRnd
randomize : nRnd = Int(1000000 * rnd)
sCmd = "mshta.exe ""javascript:{new " _
& "ActiveXObject(""InternetExplorer.Application"")" _
& ".PutProperty('" & nRnd & "',window);" _
& "window.resizeTo(" & w & "," & h & ");" _
& "window.moveTo(" & l & "," & t & ")}"""
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run sCmd, 1, False
    do until .AppActivate("javascript:{new ") : WSH.sleep 10 : loop
    end with  'WSHShell
    For Each IE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").windows
        If IsObject(IE.GetProperty(nRnd)) Then
            set HTABox = IE.GetProperty(nRnd)
            IE.Quit
            HTABox.document.title = "HTABox"
            HTABox.document.write _
            "<HTA:Application contextMenu=no border=thin " _
            & "minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no sysmenu=no SHOWINTASKBAR=no >" _
            & "<body scroll=no style='background-color:" _
            & sBgColor & ";font:normal 10pt Arial;" _
            & "border-Style:inset;border-Width:3px'" _
            & "onbeforeunload='vbscript:if not done.value then " _
            & "window.event.cancelBubble=true:" _
            & "window.event.returnValue=false:" _
            & "done.value=true:end if'>" _
            & "<input type=hidden id=done value=false>" _
            & "<center><span id=msg>&nbsp;</span><br>" _
            & "<input type=button id=btn1 value=' Log Off ' "_
            & "onclick=done.value=true><center></body>"
            HTABox.btn1.focus
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "HTA window not found."
    wsh.quit
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I hope that other people will find this useful.